# Do I Need to Reinstall Tensorflow everytime I join a virtualenv?

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

So I followed this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows and installed Tensorflow on a venv(it was installed successfully) I then deactivated then venv and then joined again to check if it was installed and it isn't anymore?

Got this message

```
(venv) C:\Users\eddie>python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
2020-07-20 16:33:41.151220: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-07-20 16:33:41.154540: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-07-20 16:33:42.469966: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-07-20 16:33:42.473332: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-07-20 16:33:42.478266: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: LAPTOP-PV67HTAL
2020-07-20 16:33:42.481952: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: LAPTOP-PV67HTAL
2020-07-20 16:33:42.483927: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-07-20 16:33:42.494211: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x29059196c40 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-20 16:33:42.499523: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
tf.Tensor(-660.95654, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

I noticed that their installation documentation says do not exit the venv until I am done using Tensorflow so does that mean I need to reinstall it everytime I join the same venv? If that is the case, is there a way to just keep it installed?

Is there a conventional setup for people who use Tensorflow? I am planning to use vscode with it, but this installation is giving me a headache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to reinstall tensorflow each time. When you activate the virtual environment all the necessary variables are being set and you have access to the libraries you have already installed in this environment.

Regarding the message: this shows that tf is installed and is working. Altough there are some warnings about missing libraries, but you got the result in the last line.

Look at the last line of your message:

```
tf.Tensor(-660.95654, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

this is the result of the

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
```

command.

Comment: Oh! I feel so stupid, I spent an hour just trying to figure out installations and was getting really frustrated thinking it wasn't working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

No you don't  Need to Reinstall Tensor flow every time u  join a virtualenv